# Orgmode #+INCLUDE: ---- Ignore text from included file, but not configuration lines

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is it possible to `#+INCLUDE: config.org` when exporting and have only the lines in `config.org` that start with `#` be included?

Say you have a file `config.org` like this:

```
Formats the style of captions. Adds margin to the caption (hang), makes the font small and puts the name of the caption in bold face.
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
```

Then I'd only want the line with `#+LATEX_HEADER` to be included. But I'd still want the previous line to remain in the `config.org` file as an explanation to what the command does.

Comment: Have a look at [SETUPFILE](https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html) instead of INCLUDE.

Comment: @Juancho I appreciate your comment, but the use case that I have does not work with setupfile. I use include to add specific configurations when exporting a subtree, and setupfile works globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your configuration into a heading and include only the heading.

```
#+INCLUDE: config.org::*Configuration
```

If the heading annoys you, add an `:ignore:` tag to it so that the heading itself is ignored on export. Be sure to eval the following Elisp code to activate the `:ignore:` feature.

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ox
    (require 'ox-extra)
    (ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines)))
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but would require to keep a copy of the comments about the configurations elsewhere, which is what I'm trying to avoid. But it does work, thanks for the suggestion. Just as a side note for other readers, to use `ox-extra` you actually need the package `org-plus-contrib` installed.